# Non-zero exit code on missing parameter with picocli

Tags: picocli

I have a simple `Command` with one mandatory parameter:

```
@Parameters(index = "0", description = "manifest")
private File manifest;
```

When I call it from the command line without a parameter I get the expected message:

```
Missing required parameter: <manifest>
Usage ....
```

BUT: the return code for the call to `java` is 0, implying everything went fine. 
Is there a way to have `picocli` return a non-zero   code if a parameter (or option) is missing/incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

> UPDATE: 
>   Since picocli 4.0 exit code support is very easy with the `execute` method.

Example with picocli 4.0:

```java
@Command
class ExitCodeDemo implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Parameters(index = "0", description = "manifest")
    private File manifest;

    public Integer call() {
        // business logic here
        return ok ? 0 : 123;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int exitCode = new CommandLine(new ExitCodeDemo()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

The above program will exit with `1` if an exception occurred in the business logic, `2` if the user input was invalid, and if everything went well, exit with either `0` or `123` depending on the business logic (see the `call` method).

If the ["standard" error codes](https://picocli.info/#_exception_exit_codes) are enough for your application, you can also implement `Runnable`.

---

Prior to picocli 4.0, applications needed to use the `parseWithHandlers` method. This is now deprecated, but here is an example. The following program will exit with exit code 456 if the user provided invalid input:

```
// OLD: for picocli versions before 4.0 (DEPRECATED)
//
@Command
class Deprecated implements Runnable {
    @Parameters(index = "0", description = "manifest")
    private File manifest;

    public void run() { 
        // business logic here
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine(new Deprecated());
        cmd.parseWithHandlers(
                new RunLast(),
                CommandLine.defaultExceptionHandler().andExit(456),
                args);
    }
}
```

There are [plans for adding better exit code support](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/561#issuecomment-464065230) to picocli in version 4.0.